# Windows vs. Ubuntu files conflict

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-10, disk

I have Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 installed in dual-boot.

I used to mount my D:/ drive while working in Ubuntu to keep files achievable from both systems.
But lately I found out that when I start Windows all files that I dropped on D:/ are erased (not just unseen from Windows, but deleted, I checked from Ubuntu later). It looks like some Windows disk checking system cleans them up as a rubbish.

Can anyone help, please?

upd:
Hibernation mode (& fast startup) are off in Windows.
Still think there's some kind of a disk-checking procedure in Windows.

Comment: Is this the entire D:/ drive being cleaned (perhaps a reformat) or just some files within it? & you presumably have a Windows virus-scanner - have you tried running clamscan (over C:/) while windows isn't running?

Comment: Are you sure the drive was mounted when you copied the files over? If not, they might be stored in the mountpoint (the directory where you mount the drive) and not on the D: itself.

Comment: I've had the same problem, but with 2 seperate machines (Lubuntu 15.04 and Windows 8.1 iirc) and an USB drive…

Comment: @terdon I tuned auto-mount for D:/ (it's in ntfs, btw), so you can see what happens here (TestOpenCV is missing after booting into Windows): [1](https://pp.vk.me/c636325/v636325596/2d490/uQFe5vc79O8.jpg), [2](https://pp.vk.me/c636325/v636325596/2d49a/Nz3bZyumhPw.jpg), [3](https://pp.vk.me/c636325/v636325596/2d4a4/0A8V9Z8OnQY.jpg)

Comment: Make sure that Windows is not hibernated in any way, Windows-fast-start-up should be disabled.

Comment: @mook765 neither hibernation mode, nor the fast-startup are on